# Global check user Logged In - NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I config a global check user if `LoggedIn` or not to rendering components in NuxtJS but I can't do it.

I write computed to wrapper components (layouts/default.vue).

**~/layouts/default.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        LoggedIn: 'authUser'
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But I can't use it on children components / pages.

**~/pages/index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="index-page">
    <div class="" v-if="LoggedIn">
      asdasd
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.LoggedIn)
    // Result: Undefined
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: a computed value is only usable inside the component where it's defined. [Vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) is more suitable here.

Comment: Could you please rewrite this code for me

Comment: no offense but shouldn't you at least try? it's not as difficult as you think

Comment: Read the docs here: https://nuxtjs.org/examples/auth-external-jwt. It is really well explained. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @JacobGoh I tried with mapGetters but It doesn't work too

Comment: @Imre_G Thank. I want to use it for components insteads of pages. So I need global `LoggedIn` data

Comment: If you use Vuex to store your auth that will always work